# Save All Images From an Image Column in a Sharepoint List to OneDrive Using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, onedrive, power-automate

I have a Sharepoint list with an image column called "Comprovante"(portuguese). I need to extract the images from that column, rename them with the title column called "Título" and save to a OneDrive folder.
Could you help or guide me? Thanks!

[My List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyyb.png)

I'm a beginner in Power Automate and I've been looking for an example flow to perform these steps but I haven't found anything similar.